# Powershell Cutting Off Display Output

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to retrieve the following properties of a network share. Even with the size set to auto it's cutting off the InheritanceFlags and not including that in the output. What's the best methodology to showing all of the properties?

```
(get-acl L:\Sharename).access | ft IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags -auto
```

The warning I'm getting is:

```
WARNING: column "InheritanceFlags" does not fit into the display and was removed.
```

Changing the Screen Buffer Size and Window Size in Powershell properties is proving to not be helpful at all.

Comment: `Out-GridView` or `Format-List`.

Comment: Thanks! Should I just add that to the end of the PS command with a | ?

Comment: https://poshoholic.com/2010/11/11/powershell-quick-tip-creating-wide-tables-with-powershell/ - `out-string` might help you, but then so might `| export-csv report.csv -notypeinformation` instead of `| ft ..` , and opening it in Excel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it's getting truncated (for me columns just end up wrapping, maybe it's a `ConEmu` thing), but `Format-List` should display the info for you vertically vs. horizontally:

```
( Get-ACL L:\Sharename ).Access |
  Format-List IdentityReference, FileSystemRights, AccessControlType, IsInherited, InheritanceFlags
```